# how do I get labels vertically on x-axis while plotting in r languauge

Tags: r, plot

I am generating a plot in R. I am not making a tree map like in the picture -- but I do want my x axis to have the variable names vertical like in the picture.

This is the code that I am using to generate the plot.

```
    library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname='postgres',user='postgres',password='postgres', port='5432', host='localhost')
b='SELECT Distinct "TypeText" as t, Count(*)as c FROM public."NewOrleans911" group by t;'
rs <- dbSendQuery(con,b)
a = dbListResults(con)
a = fetch(rs,n=-1)
data<-a$t
barplot(a$c,xlab="type", ylab="count",main="Crime Vs #",xlim=c(1,233),ylim=c(0,333555),names.arg=c(a$t),labCol=colnames(data))
```

And my data is
head(a)

```
                                  type(t)   count(c)
1                     PUBLIC WORKS ENFORCE    3
2                     DESCRICATION OF GRAV    1
3                               AUTO THEFT 9812
4 OFFICER NEEDS ASSISTANCE, LIFE IN DANGER    1
5              AGGRAVATED BATTERY DOMESTIC   10
6                     DOMESTIC CRIMINAL DA  954
```

I need my x-axis to look like the image in the link
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EkH5y0QZi7Q/Ug5pJoHzNmI/AAAAAAAAAZg/3I8Swupdu7g/s1600/Subway+Heatmap.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use argument `las`

```
   barplot(....,las=2)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. And what if I use plot() with same code and i have a same question??

Comment: You will get the same answer.